# How to send sms in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using following link for sending message.
http://www.smsjust.com/blank/sms/user/urlsms.php?username=XXXX&pass=XXXX&senderid=XXX&dest_mobileno=XXXX&msgtype=XXX&message=XXXX&response=XXXX. But how can i integrate this link with php? I want that, When i click on submit button sms is sent to the specific user and redirect to an another page.

Comment: read doc and integrate this api?

Comment: After submit click, do your process, use curl or file function to call this api and post data, and redirect

Comment: use php curl, refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: $callurl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($callurl , CURLOPT_URL, " http://www.smsjust.com/blank/sms/user/urlsms.php?username=XXXX&pass=XXXX&senderid=XXX&dest_mobileno=XXXX&msgtype=XXX&message=XXXX&response=XXXX. ;");
curl_setopt($callurl , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);





curl_exec($callurl);

curl_close($callurl); I HAVE DONE THIS BUT IT CANT WORK..

Comment: @zarana Why can't it work?

Comment: check error log what error it will return

Comment: It works Now.I have taken DND nub thats why sms was not sent.But, now i want to send message with multiple word with space but it can't take.

Comment: What are you added in msgtype and response params, I am also using this api for sending sms and all the values will be in encode form?, Thanks